# What is the technical term to join two signals with different phases?

Tags: discrete-signals, algorithms

there is a name for this:
If I have two signals with a discontinuity, arrange the phases of one signal to fit the other and not see the discontinuity.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: "Making phase-continuous" would be the only thing that comes to mind.

This rarely is what you *actually* want; trying to achieve this is typically indication of trying to solve something else. What's the *actual problem* this solves? Maybe a good term arises from that.

Comment: Signal Stitching? https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/44030/gapped-signals-how-to-stitch

Comment: It is tempting to go for "signal stitching" but it also depends very much on the waveform. Are we talking simple sinusoids here or more complex waveforms?